# Title not appearing in firefox

Tags: jquery, title

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/cgYgR/) jsfiddle that makes the title of an object appear in firefox. I am not really familiar with jquery, how can I modify this snippet if I have a div object and not an input?

The snippet:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" title="foobar"/>

if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $("input").each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var title = this.title;
        var div = $("<div>");
        div.attr({
            "class": "disabledButtonDiv",
            "faketitle": title
        });
        input.wrap(div);
        this.title = "";
    });
}
```

My line:

```
<div class="ttt" title="cancel" id="<?php echo $row2[$c][10]; ?>" onclick="CancelAd(this)"></div>
```

I changed the input to div and the class to ttt but that didn't help.

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't having `title="cancel"` in the div tag do what you need?

Comment: This is a known issue. That's why I need jquey as a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your jQuery code like:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $("div").each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var title = this.title;
        var div = $("<span>");
        div.attr({
            "class": "disabledButtonDiv",
            "faketitle": title
        });
        input.wrap(div);
        this.title = "";
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should change <input> tag in HTML to <div>, see the comment below mine. But use my javascript for better results

Comment: Thanks. What I was missing is the css of the disabledButtonDiv.